# Convert value from indexer safely to long

Tags: c#, long-integer

I have a problem getting a long value safely from indexer. Following code works OK until the value I want is null. Then the indexer returns empty string and my code throws an exception.

```
long TargetID = 0;
object _targetID = CurrentData[TargetIDKey];
if (_targetID !=null && (Convert.ToInt64(_targetID)) > 0)
    TargetID = Convert.ToInt64(_targetID);
else
    TargetID = -1;
```

How do I fix this so instead of exception I go to the else clause?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`long.TryParse`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zc2x2b1h(v=vs.110).aspx) instead.

```
long targetID;
if(_targetID == null || !long.TryParse(_targetID.ToString(), out targetID))
    targetID = -1;
```